# why 502 error in google app engine flexible environment django?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I want to deploy Django + CloudSQL (Postgresql) + app engine flexible environment in google cloud.

My app.yaml setting

```
runtime: python
#gunicorn
env : flex
entrypoint : gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1 -p 8000 config.wsgi --timeout 120

#instance_class : F4

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: icandoit-2021start:asia-northeast3:test-pybo=tcp:5434

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

gcloud app logs tail result

```
2021-02-03 11:02:17 default[20210203t195827]  [2021-02-03 11:02:17 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
2021-02-03 11:02:17 default[20210203t195827]  [2021-02-03 11:02:17 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (1)
2021-02-03 11:02:17 default[20210203t195827]  [2021-02-03 11:02:17 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-02-03 11:02:17 default[20210203t195827]  [2021-02-03 11:02:17 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2021-02-03 11:09:18 default[20210203t170353]  [2021-02-03 11:09:18 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2021-02-03 11:09:18 default[20210203t170353]  [2021-02-03 11:09:18 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2021-02-03 11:09:19 default[20210203t170353]  [2021-02-03 11:09:19 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-02-03 11:09:19 default[20210203t170353]  [2021-02-03 11:09:19 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2021-02-03 11:09:19 default[20210203t170353]  [2021-02-03 11:09:19 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2021-02-03 11:09:20 default[20210203t170353]  [2021-02-03 11:09:20 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-02-03 11:14:25 default[20210203t195827]  "GET /" 502
```

django and gunicon works normally.

Why Do I Have 502 Errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the official documentation about :

[Connecting from App Engine flexible environment to Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-app-engine-flexible)

> The runtime starts your app by running the command you specify in the
> entrypoint field in your app.yaml file. The entrypoint should start a
> web server that listens on the port specified by the PORT environment
> variable. For example:

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

> If your app meets the following requirements, App Engine will start
> your app with the gunicorn web server if you don't specify the
> entrypoint field:
>
> The root of your app directory contains a main.py file with a
> WSGI-compatible object called app.
>
> Your app does not contain Pipfile or Pipfile.lock files.
>
> App Engine will also automatically add the gunicorn to your
> requirements.txt file if you don't specify the entrypoint field.

[Python 3 Runtime Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime)